# imap "search all" scope: all folders/current folder?

Tags: search, imap, directory

I'm trying to figure out if IMAP's `search` (with args: `"unseen all"`) command works by searching all folders in a mailbox, or just the currently selected folder?

I.e. when selecting `INBOX` and issuing `search` command, it doesn't find any new messages.

```
a select "INBOX"
* 383 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
[...]
a search unseen all
* SEARCH
a OK Success
```

But when I move into a folder which has a new message, it works:

```
a select "inbox/test1/test2"
[...]
a uid search unseen all
* SEARCH 7 8 9
```

It detects three new messages, which is the truth. So my question is, is this behavior correct? Shouldn't `search unseen all` search all folders for new messages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#page-49)

> The SEARCH command **searches the
> mailbox** for messages that match
> the given searching criteria.  Searching criteria consist of one
> or more search keys.  The untagged SEARCH response from the
> server
> contains a listing of message sequence numbers corresponding to
> those messages that match the searching criteria.

where the keyword ALL refers to

> All messages **in the mailbox**; the
> default initial key for
> ANDing.

So, no, there does not appear to be a standard way to do what you're looking for (although there may well be plugins for various IMAP servers that facilitate that).

Comment: After realizing that RFC uses "mailbox" word when addressing a folder/directory, it became more clear that it is indeed a correct behavior ;). Thanks.